Digital signal processing - estimation theory - matlab
I'm taking a course in introduction to estimation theory, and a bit struggling with the course.
looking for a book that covers the LS, WLS, most likelihood estimation, Bayesian estimation topics .
Course program: 1. Estimation using the least squares method: a. Least squares criterion b. Solution in linear models c. Solution with weight matrix d. Error analysis (Markov-Gauss theorem) e. A-priori information integration f. Recursive solution g. Solving nonlinear models a. Maximum Likelihood Criterion (ML) b. Likelihood Equation c. Statistically sufficient d. Constraints on the revaluation error (such as the Rao-Cramer constraint) Properties of the likelihood estimator The maximum e. Threshold effects in revaluation 3. The Bayesian approach to parameter estimation: a. Bayesian valuation approach b. Solution according to the minimum mean square error criterion Orthogonality Principle (c) Maximum-A-Posteriori (MAP) criterion by solution d. e. Error constraints in Bayesian estimation f. Gaussian case estimation: Optimal linear estimation (filtering) of stochastic processes according to the minimum mean square error criterion (Wiener filter, Kalman filter)
I would really appreciate a book/course with theory and matlab examples.
thanks

The signal processing stack exchange is a better place to ask questions about DSP.

I found something about the LMS algorithm for estimating two parameters, in the following text that I have had for many years: Digital Signal Processing - A practical Approach by: E. C. Ifeachor and B. W. Jervis - Prentice Hall. But you might also be interested in these: Communication Systems by Simon Haykin . Wiley ; and by the same author : Adaptive Filter Theory by Prentice Hall.
